# When should I use Comparator vs Comparable?

Tags: java, comparator, pojo, comparable

I have a list of POJOs I need to sort somehow. I define a `Comprator` inside the POJO class and use it to sort the list.

Is the following way correct/best practice? Is there a better way to do it?

```
    public class CompratorTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Person> people = List.of(
                new Person("zoe", "saturday", 40),
                new Person("luca", "red", 15),
                new Person("boris", "vin", 54),
                new Person("boris", "apple", 33),
                new Person("boris", "apple", 70)
        );

        List<Person> sortedPeople =
                people.stream()
                        .sorted((person, other) -> Person.COMPARATOR.compare(person, other))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

        sortedPeople.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static
    class Person {
        final static Comparator<Person> COMPARATOR =
                Comparator.comparing((Person person) -> person.getName())
                        .thenComparing(person -> person.getSurname())
                        .thenComparing(person -> person.getAge());

        String name;
        String surname;
        int age;
    }
}
```

Output is correct, by the way.

EDIT
Adding a more classic way:

```
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class Animal implements Comparable<Animal> {

        String name;
        String race;

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Animal other) {
            if (this.name.equals(other.name)) {
                return String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(this.race, other.race);
            }

            return String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(this.name, other.name);
        }
    }
```

Which one do you think is a better solution?

Comment: It looks like the comparator defines the „natural order“ for Person objects. In this case, you should implement the Comparable interface and compareTo() instead. But basically, the implementation would look like that of your Comparator.

Comment: Or move comparator to utility class. Avoid pollution of pojo

Comment: Or simplify via using comparator.comparing(Animal::getRace)

Comment: Nitpicking, it should be `.thenComparingInt(person -> person.getAge())`. Or for lovers of method references `.thenComparingInt(Person::getAge)`. And in real life you wouldn’t define your `Person` class inside your `ComparatorTest` class, but I assume this was just for the example.

Comment: @bananas It’s opnion-based, but for my part I wouldn’t consider defining the natural order through a comparator as pollution of the POJO. Rather I’d want to avoid spreading logic that belongs together over more classes. Some regard keeping data and logic together as an object-oriented ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a substantial distinction between the use cases for `Comparator` and `Comparable`.

Implementing the `Comparable` interface is suitable for objects that have a **natural order** in your domain model. I'm not sure whether animals have a *natural order*, but if it is the case from the perspective of how your application model the animals, that's fine - that's the way to go. Otherwise, your class should not implement `Comparable`.

It's not something opinion-based, **documentation** clearly defines when these interfaces are intended to be used.

[*Comparable:*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html)

> This interface imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class
> that implements it. This ordering is referred to as the **class's
> natural ordering**, and the class's `compareTo` method is referred to as
> its natural comparison method.

[*Comparator:*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html)

> Comparators can also be used to control the order of certain data structures (such as sorted sets or sorted maps), or to **provide an ordering** for collections of **objects that don't have a natural ordering**.

Another obvious distinction, that you can define as many flavors of comparators as you need. Which is handy when there's no one specific way to compare and sort the objects. And they must have more meaningful names than `comparator`.

Personally, I don't see a huge harm in defining a couple of *comparators* as `public static final` fields, as in your example. If you have a single class that manages the instances of this type - extract the *comparators* into that class, otherwise if these objects are ubiquitous and used in many places you can leave them right inside the POJO (*that an opinion based part*).

Answer (score 0):

This is not opinion based: TL;DR implement `Comparable`:

- semantically, this is what Interfaces are designed for: they express a contract enforced by an object, a behavior of the object: if the objects are serializable, then they should implement `Serializable`, if they are comparable, then they should implement `Comparable`, etc...
- inheritance will work as expected and be more readable: if you define a `Dog` that extends `Animal`, you can implement comparison for `Dog` using the super implementation (i.e. a Dog is compared like any other `Animal`) or overriding the implementation to implement a behavior specific to `Dog`. The user of your `Dog` class simply calls `instance.compareTo(...)` without having to worry about what final static comparator she/he should call
- users of your `Animal` API know they have to implement `Comparable` when adding their own animal to the inheritance tree